# Magento 1.9 tier discount precision

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, tierprice, tiered-pricing, percentage

We have a Problem with differences in the total price of the order between our Magento Webshop and ERP.

**For example Magento (in our case 1.9.4.0) calculates this way:**

- 7.85 € (*product price*) **-** 5% (*tier disc. for 5 pcs*) **=** 7.4575 € **=>** 7.46 € (*will be rounded now*)
- 7.46 € (*tier price*) **x** 100 pcs (*qty*) **=** 746.00 € (*position total*)

**But our german ERP calculates this way:**

- 7.85 € (*product price*) **-** 5% (*tier disc. for 5 pcs*) **=** 7.4575 €
- 7.4575 € (*tier price*) **x** 100 pcs (*qty*) **=** 745.75 € (*position total*) **=>** 745.75 € (*will be rounded now*)

**Result for the order item total:**

- Mage: **746.00 €** => more or less 5% discount ( 4.97% )
- ERP: **745.75 €** => exactly 5% discount

**My reflections:**

It could be a solution to...

- ...increase the precision of the tier prices from 2 decimal places to X
- ...use percentage tier discounts instead of amounts.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a parameter in the magento configuration to increase the precision of the tier prices? ...or another easy way?
2. Do you have a recommendation for a module, which allows percentage tier discounts, calulates with all decimal places and rounds the item total at the end?
3. What are your thoughts?

Thanks and best regards,

Chris

Comment: Too bad, that there is no time to reply.

Comment: See below your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also german market ....

That price rounding was a problem since beginning, at least if you work with different tax calculation settings (incl. and excl. VAT for differnt stores).

We solved it with changing rounding to 4 decimals ... just have rewrite two methods:

- `Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice($price)`
- `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price::getEscapedValue($index = null)`

This works for normal prices. Tier/group prices are still displayed with 2 decimals, but are correctly calculated with 4 decimals. If it works for you i can share "mini-extension" code.

---

Can try https://github.com/sreichel/magento-StackExchange_4DigitPrice

Comment: Hi @sv3n,

there is time to reply, but sometimes I get a little busy. ;-)

I think your suggestion can help us, so I asked our developer to take a closer look.

Nevertheless, it would be great if you could provide us with the mini extension.

Thanks and bet regards,
Chris

Comment: @Chris added link ... if there are any problem pls raise an issue.

Comment: Thanks! We'll take a look. :-)